# Login on facebook from an android app

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

In my app I have a 2 edittext (for email and password) and a simple button "Facebook connect" and when I choose this button I want to go to sign in page of facebook. Is it possible what I am trying to do or I must login on facebook from facebook login page ? If it's possible,how should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

you have to download api from this link
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

and after that take code for facebook api of java from this link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = getOpenFacebookIntent(this);
        startActivity(i);

    }


public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.facebook", 0);
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("fb://profile/20531316728"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/facebook"));
    }
}
```

when you click on your button (or for example a facebook icon as an image button)

Your android browser will pops up and then you can login to facebook.

In the code above I use the page facebook.com/facebook to be browsed but you can use any other page you like but first you need to exctract the page's id from here:

graph.facebook.com/yourpage

(for example in code above the id is 20531316728 where you can find it in: graph.facebook.com/facebook)

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at the official Facebook Android SDK?
[android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)

Comment: Yes, I have seen these examples..In these examples,the user is login from facebook login page.

Comment: the same thing is on iPhone. by logging in from the facebook login page, you get an acess token. not sure if there is any way to obtain the token when user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

Here the idea is avoid login in your app if you have already logged into official facebook app. Otherwise it will pop up an custom dialog.